F# circular type dependencies
I'm creating a little card game using F# but I'm having a few problems due to circular type dependencies. I have the following card types (simplified):
type Monster =
    { Health: int
      Attack: int
      SkillText: string option }

type Spell =
    { EffectText: string }

type Kind =
    | Monster of Monster
    | Spell of Spell

type Card =
    { Name: string
      Image: string
      Kind: Kind
      IsPlayer: bool
      CanPlay: Board -> bool }

The idea is that, when creating a new card, it must define the conditions needed for it to be played based on the current board state.
The board type is
and Board =
    { PlayerHand: Hand
      EnemyHand: Hand
      PlayerDeck: Deck
      EnemyDeck: Deck
      PlayerField: Field
      EnemyField: Field
      PlayerGraveyard: Graveyard
      EnemyGraveyard: Graveyard }

My problem is, the types inside the Board all depend on the Card type, so I need to define it after the Card type, but the Card type depends on the Board type. I know that I could use generics to undo the cyclic dependency, but I have the following problem with it:
If I define a Board<'Card> type I would need to make all the types referenced by Board as generic. That not only seems verbose to me, but it also doesn't make a lot of sense in my application. I'll never make a hand of anything that isn't a Card. I know that I could do Card<'Board> instead, but that seems less intuitive and the same problems I have with Board<'Card> apply.
Is there any way to solve this problem without generics while staying purely functional (other than using the and keyword for every type that depends on Card)?

You have not presented a reproducible problem here, so I can't tell for sure, but it seems you misunderstand something fundamental. Are you aware that you can use the 'and' keyword multiple times in sequence?

Yes I'm. I just don't want to have all types into one big file. What can I do to make the reproducible?

What's wrong with putting all the related types in one big file?

I find it hard to manage and navigate a file with different many things, specially if I start defining members which do not care for the other types present.

In this case, the answer is no. You can't reference these types without linking them at some point with and or without generics, as far as I know.

I see. What would be the most idiomatic F# solution? A types file with type inside it using and or split everything into its own file using generics?

Use one file with just the types. Put functions that handle the types in another file, or files. It's normal to have large files in F#, as opposed to C#.

Why do you not want to use generics? I wouldnt use them unnecessarily, but they can solve this problem

I didn't want to use generics because I only want to create a board of cards. In the end I used generics, though. It seemed like the cleaner solution.

Yes! There are a number of ways of solving this problem
1. The and Keyword
I see you already used it in and Board = ... so I assume you know are aware of it but you don't want to use it. Just In case:
type Card =
    { Name: string
      Image: string
      Kind: Kind
      IsPlayer: bool
      CanPlay: Board -> bool }

and Board =
    { PlayerHand: Hand
      EnemyHand: Hand
      PlayerDeck: Deck
      EnemyDeck: Deck
      PlayerField: Field
      EnemyField: Field
      PlayerGraveyard: Graveyard
      EnemyGraveyard: Graveyard }

This lets you write circular types together, but they must be in the same file.
2. Break Down Your Dependency
This depends on the game you have in mind, but maybe CanPlay does not need to depend on board? Usually things like this can be a simple enum:
type PlayCondition =
    | BoardIsEmpty
    | ManaIsAbove of int

type Card =
    { Name: string
      Image: string
      Kind: Kind
      IsPlayer: bool
      CanPlay: PlayCondition }

3. Use an Interface
Define your interface with the functions you want to use on the board:
type IBoard =
    abstract member GetCardAt: x: int -> y: int -> Card

and Card =
    { Name: string
      Image: string
      Kind: Kind
      IsPlayer: bool
      CanPlay: IBoard -> bool }

Implement it on board:
type Board =
    { PlayerHand: Hand
      EnemyHand: Hand
      PlayerDeck: Deck
      EnemyDeck: Deck
      PlayerField: Field
      EnemyField: Field
      PlayerGraveyard: Graveyard
      EnemyGraveyard: Graveyard }
    interface IBoard with
        member this.GetCardAt x y = ...

Hope this helps!

Thanks, I didn't know that records could implement interfaces. I ended up using generics, but I might give option 2 a try for normal summons (I'm taking inspirations from old school YGO), but special summons might need to know the board state (e.g., amount of cards in hand, field, etc)

I know you said "Is there any way to solve this problem without generics", so I assume you know the below solution, but maybe for other people reading this.
I'm not sure why you would not want to use generics, they can 'pollute' your type space and make things harder to comprehend but you can hide the parameter (I've put some dummy types in).
type Hand = Hand
type Deck = Deck
type Field = Field
type Graveyard = Graveyard

type Monster =
    { Health: int
      Attack: int
      SkillText: string option }

type Spell =
    { EffectText: string }

type Kind =
    | Monster of Monster
    | Spell of Spell

type Card<'board> =
    { Name: string
      Image: string
      Kind: Kind
      IsPlayer: bool
      CanPlay: 'board -> bool }

type Board =
    { PlayerHand: Hand
      EnemyHand: Hand
      PlayerDeck: Deck
      EnemyDeck: Deck
      PlayerField: Field
      EnemyField: Field
      PlayerGraveyard: Graveyard
      EnemyGraveyard: Graveyard }

type Card = Card of Card<Board>

